How salt and sugar acts as substitute for Oral Rehydration Solution?
So we learned that sugar+salt solution works as a homemade remedy for diarrhoea just as good as commercial powders. In our region, it is more popular that commercial ORS(Oral Rehydration Solution)
After reading about the mechanism, I somewhat got why glucose is added to ORS and sucrose on hydrolysis gives glucose+fructose so that is understood (because of symport transport of glucose and sodium).
But homemade ORS has only NaCl electrolyte. While diarrhoea causes loss/malabsorptiob of multiple electrolytes. Of the three most important minerals, Ca is stored in bones so it's levels can be maintained.
But I remember learning that slightest change in potassium concentration has adverse effects. And that hypokalemia is more dangerous than hyponatremia.
Even commercial ORS has potassium but we don't do anything about it in this case. Also Na-K balance is mostly maintained by active antiport pumps, so doesn't consuming only sodium make it more dangerous??
How is potassium imbalance restored here??
My attempt:
I remember reading in an article, that stated that body has preference when it comes to maintaining homeostasis. I can't find the link but the article stated that water has higher priority than others substances when it comes to homeostasis. Maybe potassium has higher priority than sodium.

Also as a final request, if priority exists among maintaining homeostasis of all different entities, please suggest a resource to read it.

Please spell out acronyms on first use (ORS). Also, you state that homemade ORS is made from sugar+salt but then later say it's made from salt only. Which is it?

@CareyGregory Sorry. Homemade one has sugar+salt. I wrote NaCl only because it's the only electrolyte.

In diarrhoea, water conservation should require release of ADH and Aldosterone From here , both reabsorb sodium and remove potassium and yet sugar+NaCl is sufficient. Adds to the confusion. Also iirc, the major role of glucose in commercial ORS is to increase Na absorption.
